# three.js fog not rendering?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to add fog to my scene but it just won't render?

I have done some searching but there seem to be no answer to my problem. Here is a screenshot of the problem

[image: no fog]

This is the code demo: https://jsfiddle.net/7orbmn4t/

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xcce0ff);
scene.fog = new THREE.Fog(0xff0000, 10, 500);

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
  90,
  window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
  0.1,
  1000
);

camera.rotation.x = 0.7853;
camera.position.set(0, 0, 15);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xffffff ) );

var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(100, 100, 0);
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
  color: 0x898989,
  fog: true
});
var plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(plane);

renderer.render(scene, camera);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
```

Comment: Is the grey portion meant to be the fog? It's just too opaque, correct?

Comment: thanks for your reply. the grey portion is not the fog, its a plane object

Answer (score 0):

The `fog` flag in a material only specifies if the material is *affected* by fog: [material.fog](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/Material.fog)

It doesn't create fog. To do that, you need to create fog first: [Fog](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/scenes/Fog)

Comment: thanks for your reply! i have already added a fog: 
`scene.fog = new THREE.Fog(0xff0000, 10, 500);`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that. Changing the fog to `new THREE.Fog(0xff0000, 10, 50);` made a difference for me: https://jsfiddle.net/tb91dnok/

Comment: thanks :) it worked. must be because of the fog range